# Finding 95% upper confidence bound for $\theta$ if your sample follows the uniform distribution

Tags: probability, statistical-inference

If you have a random sample of size $n = 20$ from a uniform distribution on the interval $(0,\theta)$, find a $95$% upper confidence bound for $\theta$

So I tried using Chi square  but it didn't work.  Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$
F_{X_{(n})}(t) = (F_{X}(t))^n = \frac{t ^ n}{\theta ^ n}
$$
hence, as $F(F^{-1}(x))=x$,
$$
{n}\sqrt{\frac{X_{(n)}}{\theta}} \sim U[0,1],
$$
namely, 
$$
\mathbb{P}\left( {n}\sqrt{\frac{X_{(n)}}{\theta}}\le 0.95\right) = 0.95,
$$
$$
\mathbb{P}\left( \theta \ge X_{(n)}/0.95^{1/n}\right) = 0.95.
$$

Comment: Is this upper bound or lower bound? OP is for upper bound..

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

You know for sure that $\theta \ge m:=\max_{i=1}^{20} x_i,$ so consider an interval of the form $[m,m+\delta].$ You need to choose $\delta$ just large enough so that $P(\theta\in [m,m+\delta]) =0.95.$

$\theta\in[m,m+\delta]$ if and only if $\max x_i > \theta -\delta,$ so you need to compute $P(\max x_i > \theta-\delta).$

Comment: sorry I didn't progress much from your hint.

Comment: @Itsnhantransitive Well, you need to explain where you're having trouble. Do you know the definition of a confidence interval? Do you understand why $\theta \ge \max_i x_i $ with probability one? Do you know how to compute the cumulative distribution of the maximum of a sample?